# p:booleanCheckBox save value to map

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to save the values of booleanSelectBoxes to a map.

In my bean I've this map (with getter + setter for sure):

```
private Map<String, Boolean> selectedPermissions;
```

I fill the map in my bean by default, it looks like this then:

```
{0;0=false, 0;1=false, 0;2=false, 1;0=false, 1;1=false, 1;2=false}
```

My view:

```
<ui:repeat var="document" value="#{group.documents.entrySet().toArray()}"> 
    <ui:repeat var="right" value="#{group.rights.entrySet().toArray()}"> 
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="
         #{GroupBean.selectedPermissions[#{right.value};#{document.value}]}" />
    </ui:repeat>
 </ui:repeat>
```

right and document are both treemaps with String as key and String as value.

My problem is the value of the booleanCheckBox. I can't find a way to combine the value of right and document with a semicolon. I always get a NumberFormatException.

Using a map as value shouldn't be a problem according to this post: [How to map the value of a h:selectBooleanCheckbox in a h:dataTable within a h:dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589473/how-to-map-the-value-of-a-hselectbooleancheckbox-in-a-hdatatable-within-a-hda)

But what's the correct syntax of the checkboxValue to find the associated key and set his value in the selectedPermissions map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. You need to link strings with concat in the view, so this one works:

```
<ui:repeat var="document" value="#{group.documents.entrySet().toArray()}"> 
    <ui:repeat var="right" value="#{group.rights.entrySet().toArray()}"> 
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="
         #{GroupBean.selectedPermissions[(right.value).concat(';').concat(document.value)]}" />
    </ui:repeat>
 </ui:repeat>
```